# TimeZone Information Not Formatted Correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I'm trying to format time to the user's timezone information. I'm using date-fns and date-fns-tz libraries to do that. Below is the code and output:

```
const utcToZonedTime = require('date-fns-tz/utcToZonedTime') 
const formatDate = require('date-fns-tz/format') 
const enGB = require('date-fns/locale/en-GB')

//tz is set to America/Los_Angeles
let tempDT = utcToZonedTime(new Date(classStartTime), tz)
tempDT = formatDate(tempDT, 'dd-MMM HH:mm a zzz', { timeZone: tz, locale: enGB})
console.log('tempDT', tempDT)
//This prints 13-Aug 07:30 AM GMT-7
```

What I need is 13-Aug 07:30 AM PST. When I use zzzz as timezone formatter, it does print the full name of timezone. But, short name is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is it `PST`? Pacific? Philippines? Pakistan? All 3 have the PST abbreviation. I assume (but not sure) en_GB doesn't know what it is the best option (for a GB person).

Comment: BTW one PST is GMT-8. PDT is GMT-7

Comment: Using zzzz prints "Pacific Daylight Time", so using zzz should print PDT? But it prints GMT-7

Comment: According to the [date-fns documentation](https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/format), there is no token for timezone name, only various tokens (based on O, X, Z, z) for  different formats of offset (+0, +00:00, GMT+00:00, etc.). Timezone names are not standardised, nor are abbreviations. For me, "xxxx" produces an offset like +0600.

Comment: That's why date-fns recommends to use date-fns-tz library. This library has specific functions to format the timezone https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz#format

Comment: @VikalpJain—according to the linked documentation, date-fns-tz uses the Intl API for the values for the long and short timezone options. Testing with different *timeZone* values shows that sometimes it returns an abbreviation (e.g. EDT) and sometimes an offset (e.g. GMT+10). The Intl API does not define a mapping for language to format, it just says use data from the [CLDR project](http://cldr.unicode.org). There might be consistency for certain language/timezone/location values, but no certainty that all implementations will produce an abbreviation or offset for all combinations.